# Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook Unity SDK. Is there any way by which Facebook registration can be done from within app. Currently, when calling FB.Login function Facebook app or safari browser is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved yet with the current version of the Facebook SDK

Comment: Yeah, it cannot be done atleast using unity plugin. Had to write the custom implementation for that. 

I am checking if player is signed in into iOS social Facebook then use the custom implementation. Else just keep using Facebook unity SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid this modifying the EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs file

Comment: How? More detail, please.